# kendo grid expand to fit all columns

Tags: css, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo UI grid with 20 columns, all of which have text data.

When Kendo renders the grid, every column (and column heading) has an ellipsis (...) indicating that the content was truncated.

I've created an example of this here: http://dojo.telerik.com/iRIqU

It seems like the grid width adapts to the width of the container it's in - rather than forcing the necessary width to display all data, and scrolling horizontally.

Is there a way to achieve this, so all the data is readable? (i.e. the way Format > Column > AutoFit Selection works in Excel.)

I've tried

1. changing the TD style with `whitespace: nowrap;`, but this just causes the text to overlap into each column
2. setting the `grid` to `resizeable:true` and calling, e.g. `grid.autoFitColumn(1);` - but all this does is *reduce* the width of column 1 to better accommodate the other columns in my grid

Comment: There is a `Width` property you can set for each column in your grid code. Give that a try.

Comment: I want the `width` to be as wide as the longest content for that column, not a fixed value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/autofitcolumn) it's better to call `grid.autoFitColumn` only after the Grid has been databound.

Also be aware that:

> Auto-fitting all columns at once is a resource-intensive operation and
>   is not recommended.

See my fixed example: http://dojo.telerik.com/iRIqU/2

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      type: "odata",
      transport: {
        read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
      },
      schema: {
        model: {
          fields: {
            OrderID: {
              type: "number"
            },
            ShipCountry: {
              type: "string"
            },
            ShipCity: {
              type: "string"
            },
            ShipName: {
              type: "string"
            },
            OrderDate: {
              type: "date"
            },
            ShippedDate: {
              type: "date"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      pageSize: 15
    },
    height: 550,
    sortable: true,
    resizable: true,
    pageable: true,
    dataBound: function(e) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.columns.length; i++) {
        this.autoFitColumn(i);
      }
    },
    columns: [{
        field: "OrderDate",
        title: "Order Date",
        format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
      },
      {
        field: "ShipCountry",
        title: "Ship Country"
      },
      {
        field: "ShipCity",
        title: "Ship City"
      },
      {
        field: "ShipName",
        title: "Ship Name"
      },
      {
        field: "ShippedDate",
        title: "Shipped Date",
        format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
      },
      {
        field: "OrderID",
        title: "ID"
      }, {
        field: "OrderDate",
        title: "Order Date",
        format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
      },
      {
        field: "ShipCountry",
        title: "Ship Country"
      },
      {
        field: "ShipCity",
        title: "Ship City"
      },
      {
        field: "ShipName",
        title: "Ship Name"
      },
      {
        field: "ShippedDate",
        title: "Shipped Date",
        format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
      },
      {
        field: "OrderID",
        title: "ID"
      }
    ]
  });

  //grid.autoResizeColumn(1);
  //grid.autoResizeColumn(2);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <div id="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure why but i'm getting `autoFitColumn is not a function`

Comment: this for loop cause to not work horizontal scrolling. How can we have both autoFitColumn   for all collumns and horizontal scroll?